# Regex for certain character and anything after that

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I need to call minus/hyphen (-) as minus when it comes between one number or any other character.
otherwise, if it comes between characters I need to replace it with an empty string.

For replacing '-' to empty string

```
readOutText = 'akhila-hegde'
readOutText = readOutText.replace(/([A-Za-z])-([A-Za-z]){0}\w/gi, ' '); // replace '-' with ' '
```

Now replace '-' with 'minus' in all of the scenarios

```
9 - {{response}}
9-{{response}}
{{response}}-9
{{response}} - 9
7346788-literallyanything
literallyanything-347583475
```

I am trying expression in this in this site https://regexr.com/

I have tried a couple of RegEX for `9-{{response}}`  tyeps.

```
readOutText = readOutText.replace(/([0-9])[ ]{0,1}-[ ]*\w/gi, ' minus '); // Not working 
readOutText = readOutText.replace(/([0-9])[ ]{0,1}-([a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/? ])\w/gi, ' minus ')
```

Both of these are matching with `9-{` in the string `9-{{response}}`

If I know the above type I can do the same for `{{response}}-473` type

Can someone help me with what I have missed?

Comment: if you want to say 0 or more you use the `*` if you want to say 1 or more you use the `+` If you want to say Hi followed by 0 or more anything you do Hi.* Consider playing with a visualizer such as https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=Hi.*

Answer (score 2):

I made a small example using capture groups to capture the hyphen and classify as minus or true hpyhen. https://regex101.com/r/zb2eZv/1

Capture Group 1 is minus and capture group 2 is hyphen.

```
(?:\d+(-)\d+)|(?:\w+(-)\w+)
```

[image: regex visualization]

https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%3F%3A%5Cd%2B(-)%5Cd%2B)%7C(%3F%3A%5Cw%2B(-)%5Cw%2B)

Comment: How did you generate this REGEX diagram. I kinda love its representation and very easy to understand.

Comment: What about `7346788-literallyanything` (digit-letter) and `literallyanything-347583475` (letter-digit) ? Will this work?

Comment: seems like it does. You can easily check yourself my using the first link in my answer and play with the regex.

Comment: it both those cases will be marked as group 2 so no minus but a hyphen.

Comment: Hey, space is considered here? before / after '-' ?

Comment: no you cannot put a space at those places. If you want to to this you need to add `\s*` before and after the catpure groups

Answer (score 1):

It's a litte resource-intensive, and there might be cleverer solutions, but I believe you need a multipass `replace`.

- Replace in case of `digit dash digit`
- Replace in case of `digit dash not-digit`
- Replace in case of `not-digit dash digit`

This will ignore all `non-digit dash non-digit` cases.

By the way, `[0-9]` can be replaced with `\d` (digit) and `[ ]{0,1}` can be replaced with  `*` (zero or more spaces).

```js
const inputs = [
    "akhila-hegde",
    "6 -4",
    "9 - {{response}}",
    "9-{{response}}",
    "{{response}}-9",
    "{{response}} - 9",
    "7346788-literallyanything",
    "literallyanything-347583475",
    "7- 8 and some-composed - word then 4-9"
];

const transformMinus = word => word
                .replace(/(\d) *- *(\d)/g, "$1 minus $2")
                .replace(/(\d) *- *(\D)/g, "$1 minus $2")
                .replace(/(\D) *- *(\d)/g, "$1 minus $2")


const outputs = inputs.map(transformMinus);

console.log(outputs);
```